# Passing variables from partial template to main template (play framework)

Tags: javascript, css, playframework, template-engine

Hy,
I'm making an application with the playframework. Now I've encountered a problem too which i don't seem to find an answer.

I have a main template which takes the following arguments:

```
@(title: String, active: Int)(content: Html)(style: Html)(js: Html)
```

This is intended so I can put all the stylesheets at the top of the page and the javascripts at the end (using the variables @style and @js).
So my templates have this structure

```
@(arguments of template...) {
    <!-- html content -->
} { <!-- stylesheets --> } { <!-- javascripts --> }
```

So far so good. But the problem occurs when I have a seperate template. For example: I have a small template that can display error messages. These errors require seperate css stylesheets/javascripts

```
@(errorMessage: String) {
    <div class="special-error" onclick="special-error-function">
        @errorMessage
    </div>
}
```

Now I have a file "error.css" and "error.js". These should only be included when there actually is an error. So that I can call it in my view like this:

```
@(arguments of template...) {
    <!-- html content -->
    @errorTemplate("This page has an error.")
} { <!-- stylesheets --> } { <!-- javascripts --> }
```

The point is that I would 'somehow' like to be able, to (implicitly) pass the variables @js and @stylesheets tot the errorTemplate, than edit these variables (add the "error.css" and "error.js") in the errorTemplate. The pass them back to the view template. And than pass these to the main template as usual.

Comment: not possible to change the value of arguments in template because they are of `val` type.

Comment: @genz This is vague. What template is the error template being rendered inside? It sounds like you just want a variation of the main template.. but it's hard to tell.

Comment: I'll update my post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

In your main template in the section

```
{ <!-- stylesheets --> }
```

you can conditionnaly add the error stylesheet if your have to show error messages.

This is the same condition you should have in your template to decide if you integrate the error template

Comment: This is one suggestions. The problem is that I want to avoid to write the condition in every template where I would possibly need the errorTemplate

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an argument to your main template that tells it whether or not to add the error stylesheet and script. Your main template handles the conditional statement and your other views just pass a true/false.

**main.scala.html**

```
@(title: String, active: Int, hasErrors: Boolean = false)(content: Html)(style: Html)(js: Html)
<html>
  <head>
    <title>@title</title>
    @style
    @if(hasErrors){<link rel="stylesheet" href="error.css" />}
  </head>
  <body>

    ...

    @js
    @if(hasErrors){<script src="error.js"></script>}

  </body>
</html>
```

**other.scala.html** (For example)

```
@(form: Form[MyModel])
@main(title, active, form.hasErrors) {
  ...
  @if(form.hasErrors){
    @errorTemplate(errorMessage)
  }
  ...
} {
  <!-- stylesheets -->
} {
  <!-- javascripts -->
}
```